# Dell Replay Manager vs/Actifio or Veeam

Tags: dell, veeam

I am not very familiar with SAN storage.  The company I work for is evaluating a backup solution that will utilize two Dell Compellents.  We currently have one Compellent, but are considering purchasing another for a warm site.  The quote for the second Compellent includes two instances of Dell Replay Manager.  My understanding is that Dell Replay  Manager can be used to take snapshots, which is understandably a good idea.  We are also evaluating Actifio and Veeam as backup solutions.  The Dell Replay Manager is pretty expensive and I am wondering if it is even needed if we will be using Veeam or Actifio for a backup solution.

Could anyone offer any insight as to why, or why we would not, want to eliminate the Dell  Replay Manager from our purchase IF we proceed with a true backup solution (Veeam or Actifio) ?

Apologies if this question is naive and better suited for a different forum.

Thanks

Comment: Turns out that we probably don't need Replay Manager if we implement Actifio as a backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Dell backup as long as you operate with virtual systems and VMs (VMware or Hyper-V hypervisors). Veeam is a standard of backup solution there. Veeam supersedes its analogs, offering backup and virtualization 2 in 1, any storage as a backup target, plus some cool features like backup encryption and backup to cloud. And it's cheaper...

If you, however, deal with physical or hybrid systems, that's another case.